# how to get cpu usage of azure vm throught powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

can we see the metrics of the CPU usage and other details of the VM through power shell.
i am trying to write a power shell script to get all the details of the azure virtual machine it show some error can any one have idea about how to write a script to get the details.

---

i am able to get the vm details Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "RG" -Name "VM" -Status but i am not getting cpu usage for that i tried some table contents "WADPerformanceCountersTable" rule:- "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"

Comment: What have you tried ? Show your piece of effort. SO is not for script delivery, it's for helping people if they are stuck somewhere.

Comment: @luckygirl Edit the question and put your code over there. So that we can take a look at it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe we can use this Azure PowerShell command `Get-AzureRmMetric` to get CPU usage.

We can use `Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition` to get the supported metrics, here are the metrics of Azure VM:

```
PS D:\testdata> (Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId $id).name

Value                     LocalizedValue
-----                     --------------
Percentage CPU            Percentage CPU
Network In                Network In
Network Out               Network Out
Disk Read Bytes           Disk Read Bytes
Disk Write Bytes          Disk Write Bytes
Disk Read Operations/Sec  Disk Read Operations/Sec
Disk Write Operations/Sec Disk Write Operations/Sec
CPU Credits Remaining     CPU Credits Remaining
CPU Credits Consumed      CPU Credits Consumed
```

More information about supported metrics of Azure VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines).

Then we can use the value to get metrics:

```
Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $id -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput -MetricNames "Network in"
```

Here is the PowerShell output:

[image]

If your Azure PowerShell version is 3.4.0, we can use this command to get guest metrics:

[image]

Hope it helps:)