# How to get "Network In" and "Network Out" from Azure metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring

I have a Virtual machine in Azure VM and I want to get Network-In/Network-Out metrics.
From Azure portal, I set Diagnostics settings and metrics are storing into the selected storage table. but there is some different between stored metrics and what I can see in Azure portal.
In Azure portal I can select `Network In` and `Network Out` from the Metrics list (see screenshot below):
[image: Selecting metrics from Azure Portal]
As you can see, the name of metric here is `Network In` and `Network Out` and it is showing the VM network's usage.

But in the storage table, it is showing different list of metrics and it is aggregated. `CounterName` of saved metrics in storage table are listed bellow:

- \NetworkInterface\BytesReceived
- \NetworkInterface\BytesTotal
- \NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted
- \NetworkInterface\PacketsReceived
- \NetworkInterface\PacketsTransmitted
- \NetworkInterface\TotalCollisions
- \NetworkInterface\TotalRxErrors

I was thinking that `\NetworkInterface\BytesReceived` and `\NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted` are same as `Network In` and `Network Out`. but it is aggregated and it's not Transmitted byte for each minute. it's aggregated to all other metrics before current minute. please see bellow screenshot:
[image: aggregation network metric]
Then the question is how I should get `Network In` and `Network Out` metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, maybe you can use Azure PowerShell command to get that:

```
Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $id -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput -MetricNames "Network in"
```

Output like this:

[image]

More information about supported metrics of Azure VM, please refer [to this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines).

Here a similar case about you, [please refer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667074/how-to-get-cpu-usage-of-azure-vm-throught-powershell/46678157#46678157).

Comment: Ye, Thank you. it is working but is there any way to save these metrics into the azure storage? like what I can do from Diagnostics settings

Comment: @RezaAmya Sorry for the delay, based on my knowledge, we can't save these metrics into the Azure storage, but you can export those metrics to your local server with PowerShell. hope this helps:)