# How to get cpu usage of Azure resources through PowerShell with Az module

Tags: azure, powershell

this is a revamped version of this post: [how to get cpu usage of azure vm throught powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667074/how-to-get-cpu-usage-of-azure-vm-throught-powershell)

With the Az module replacing the old AzureRM, what would be the equivalent of Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition? More importantly, how do you guys check the equivalent new cmdlets between the two modules, is there any documentation around on this?

I can see two modules which could be related, Az.ApplicationInsights and Az.OperationalInsights but I can't find any cmdlet which has *Metric* as part of its name.

I'm looking to retrieve CPU and RAM usage out of our AKS cluster nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
It's in the Az.Monitor module: Get-AzMetricDefinition.

As a rule of thumb, everything which was Action-AzureRM* became Action-Az*.